# jquery : If url contains string x change backgroud color of specific tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background-color

I want to change color backgroud of tag in my code depending on URL. If url contains **Suisse**, it changes the background color to green for the tag `#switch-univers li a.bilgroup`

**JS**

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("Suisse") > -1) {
  $('#switch-univers li a.bilgroup').css({ backgroundColor, 'green' });
} else if window.location.href.indexOf("Sales") > -1) {
  $('#switch-univers li a.sales').css({ backgroundColor, 'blue' });
} else if (window.location.href.indexOf("My%20desktop") > -1) {
  $('#switch-univers li a.lifebil').css({ backgroundColor, 'pink' });
}
```

And My HTML is :

```
<body>
  <Div id= « switch-univers » >
    <li><a class=“bilgroup“>Suisse</a></li>
    <li><a class=“sales“>Sales</a></li>
    <li><a class=“lifebil“>My desktop</a>
    </li>
  </div>
</body>
```

Nothing happen...
Any Suggestions

Comment: The quotes in your html are invalid **“**

Comment: wrap the code in $(document).ready(function()}); if the script is placed in head tag.

Comment: In this case, Suisse is not a URL, its just the content of the <a> tag. To be URL, it's necessary to be inside a href= attribute into the <a> tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
<div id="switch-univers">
    <li><a class="bilgroup">Suisse</a></li>
    <li><a class="sales">Sales</a></li>
    <li><a class="lifebil">My desktop</a>
    </li>
</div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 if (window.location.href.indexOf("Suisse") > -1) {
  $('#switch-univers li a.bilgroup').css('background-color', 'green');
 } else if window.location.href.indexOf("Sales") > -1) {
  $('#switch-univers li a.sales').css('background-color', 'blue');
 } else if (window.location.href.indexOf("My%20desktop") > -1) {
  $('#switch-univers li a.lifebil').css('background-color', 'pink');
 }
});
```